# Doing calculations in ASP.NET using buttons

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to do a super simple interface where a user enters their Principle Amount, Yearly Percentage Interests Rate, and Loan Term. The calculate fields of Monthly Payment, Sum of Payments, total Interests paid. I'm doing the calculation but keep getting errors and it seems like the decimal places are not being carried over throughout the calculations?

```
Protected Sub btncalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalculate.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim P As Integer
    Dim yr As Integer
    Dim ra As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    n = CInt(txtmonths.Text)
    P = CInt(txtprinciple.Text)
    yr = CInt(txtyearlypercent.Text)

    ra = (yr / 100) / 12

    r = (P * ra) / (1 - (1 / (1 + ra) ^ n))

    lblmonpayments.Text = r.ToString("c")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error message is `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow`?

The reason you're getting this error is because `ra` and `r` are both assigned as `Integer`. However these are used for calculation that are using divide. The results will most likely return a decimal number and not a whole number. Simply change the variables to use `Decimal`

```
Protected Sub btncalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalculate.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim P As Integer
    Dim yr As Integer
    Dim ra As Decimal
    Dim r As Decimal

    n = CInt(txtmonths.Text)
    P = CInt(txtprinciple.Text)
    yr = CInt(txtyearlypercent.Text)

    ra = (yr / 100) / 12

    r = (P * ra) / (1 - (1 / (1 + ra) ^ n))

    lblmonpayments.Text = r.ToString("c")

End Sub
```